# Can 44 be a factor of $(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ where n is a natural number greater than 3?

Tags: factorial

Can 44 be a factor of $(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ where n is a natural number greater than 3 ?

When $n =4 $,

$(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7$

Comment: Try $n = 11$. Or maybe $n = 8$.

Comment: I was thinking about $n = 44$.

Comment: SInce $44=2^2\cdot{11}$, As long as one of the numbers is divisible by 11, because you'll always have 2 even numbers to take care of the 4, 44 will be a factor.

Comment: So, to conclude: $44$ is a factor, iff $n\not\equiv 4,5,6,7\pmod{11}$.

Comment: you want the smallest n ?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, $4$ is a factor. Let $n=11m+k\ (0\le k\le 10)$. If $4\le k\le 7$ then $11$ is not a factor, else it is.

Answer (score 0):

Any natural number of the form 
$$y = x\text{ mod 11 }$$
where $x = 4,5,6,7$ will not be a solution.  All others will.

For example, 
$$15 = 4 \text{ mod } 11$$
$$12\cdot{13}\cdot{14}\cdot{15}\cdot{16}\cdot{17}\cdot{18}$$
is not a solution but
$$19 = 8 \text{ mod 11 }$$
$$16\cdot{17}\cdot{18}\cdot{19}\cdot{20}\cdot{21}\cdot{22}$$
is a solution